# Selenium Ruby get href of a link of type css

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to get href of following element using Ruby Selenium WebDriver?

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://host/public-theme/css/main.css">
```

Thanks,
Sameer

Comment: you can always use  nokogiri for parsing

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get it using this code. doc = Nokogiri::HTML(driver.page_source)

        doc.css('link[rel=stylesheet]').each do |e|
                puts e['href']
        end

Comment: If the above answer solved your problem, please provide an answer below and mark it as a right answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rejin suggested, used nokogiri to parse HTML and found CSS links.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(driver.page_source) 
doc.css('link[rel=stylesheet]').each do |e| 
puts e['href']
end
```